# Render JSON in HTML Table with Django/JavaScript

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Friends, I need your help!

I am new to Python / Django and I am doing this project with the knowledge I get from day to day studying.

I have a function in my views.py that communicates with an API and returns a result in Json. The result is basically this:

```
[
{
"_id": "5d6f28ec02523e0012a4eae6",
"pass": false,
"renderSatisfaction": false,
"botTimeOut": false,
"ignore": false,
"exit": false,
"errorslog": [],
"chaterroslog": [],
"Historic": [],
"userID": "5b43b8a48b769470363b58909a9049",
"user_key": "ABCD",
"username": "Igor Miranda",
"Created_at": "2019-09-04T03: 01: 00.716Z",
"__v": 0
}
{
"_id": "5d6f291d55d3f500402d338e",
"pass": false,
"renderSatisfaction": false,
"botTimeOut": false,
"ignore": false,
"exit": false,
"errorslog": [],
"chaterroslog": [],
"Historic": [],
"userID": "577a55a043aab2a6aa78586b2520392",
"user_key": "ABCD",
"username": "Igor Miranda",
"Created_at": "2019-09-04T03: 01: 49.484Z",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

I need to render this result inside a table in an HTML page with Django, where I have the result of the fields "username", "username_key" and "history".

I've read a lot of topics here on StackOverFlow, but I still can't solve my need.

Follows my views.py, ConsumimirApi.html files and the result on the page.

views.py

```
def ConsumirApi(request):
url = 'http://urlapi.test.com.br'
body = {"start": "2019-09-04 19:30:00", "end": "2019-09-04 23:59:59"}
response = orders.post (url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth ('123456', 'password1234'),
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application / json'}, json = body)
result = json.loads (response.content)

output_result = [{k: v for k, v in x.items () if k in ["History", "user_name", "user_key"]} for x in result]
drop_falsey = lambda path, key, value: bool (value)
clean = remap (exit_ result, visit = drop_falsey)
final_result = json.dumps (clean, indent = 4, sort_keys = True)

return TemplateResponse (request, 'ConsumirApi.html', {"final_result": final_result})
```

ConsumirApi.html

```
<table id = "test_table" class = "display table with table border table with table border" border = "1" cellpacing = "0" width = "100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> user_name </th>
<th> user_key </th>
<th> History </th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<script type = "text / javascript">
$ (document) .ready (function () {

var json = {{response.content | safe }}

$ ('# test_table'). DataTable ({
final result: json.final_result, // get the data array of the object
"columns": [
{"final_result": "user_key"},
{"final_result": "username"},
{"final_result": "History"}]
});
});
</script>
```

[image of the page result, with no table created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWbta.png)
Could someone help me identify where I am going wrong or if something is missing? Some items that some people use functions within the models.py file, but I have nothing inside this file, is it really necessary to have something in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, that's the name of the dictionary you passed through

`var json = {{final_result | safe }}`